# JAVA: Problems on Zipping Folders

Tags: java, eclipse

Here's my code on Zipping Folder:

```
List<String> filesListInDir = new ArrayList<String>();
public void populateFilesList(File dir) throws IOException {
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for(File file : files){
        if(file.isFile()) filesListInDir.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        else populateFilesList(file);
    }
}
public void zipDirectory(File dir, String zipDirName) {
    try {
        populateFilesList(dir);
        //now zip files one by one
        //create ZipOutputStream to write to the zip file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipDirName);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        for(String filePath : filesListInDir){
            System.out.println("Zipping "+filePath);
            //for ZipEntry we need to keep only relative file path, so we used substring on absolute path
            ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(filePath.substring(dir.getAbsolutePath().length()+1, filePath.length()));
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);
            //read the file and write to ZipOutputStream
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            zos.closeEntry();
            fis.close();
        }
        zos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My Problem is I have 2 Folders(Folder_1 and Folder_2) in one directory(Main_Folder). When Zipping Folder_1, the zip file include Folder_2. How can I remove the Folder_2 on my Folder_1.zip?

**Here's my Point**

- **Main_Folder**

  - **Folder_1**

    - asd.sql
    - asd2.sql
    - asd3.sql
  - **Folder_2**

    - asd.jar

When Zipping Folder_1 it consists of

- **Folder_1.zip**

  - h //This folder consists the files on Folder_2. So I need to REMOVE this folder
  - asd.sql
  - asd2.sql
  - asd3.sql

Are there any method or ideas for me to remove this "h" folder in zipping folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect since you are using instace variable `filesListInDir` to store files before zipping
you have previously loaded files in that, better to clear that one at the end of `zipDirectory`, And I am assuming you are not using this in a Multi-threaded environment because it will play odd because of state variables.

```
public void zipDirectory(File dir, String zipDirName) {
    try {
        populateFilesList(dir);
        //now zip files one by one
        //create ZipOutputStream to write to the zip file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipDirName);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        for(String filePath : filesListInDir){
            System.out.println("Zipping "+filePath);
            //for ZipEntry we need to keep only relative file path, so we used substring on absolute path
            ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(filePath.substring(dir.getAbsolutePath().length()+1, filePath.length()));
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);
            //read the file and write to ZipOutputStream
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            zos.closeEntry();
            fis.close();
        }
        zos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        filesListInDir.clear(); // Clear the files 
    }
}
```